# Parse XML to a different kind of source for QML's ListView

Tags: xml, qt, listview, qml

Using QML, I have the usual `XmlListModel` in which I manually load data in my app upon start. This data is then displayed in a `ListView`. Finally, I can save the same data, cycling trough the listview's indexes and creating 'XML' strings that I patch together dynamically to create the same whole XML again and save it to disk using C++'s `QTextStream`. Easy and straightforward.

I would now like to edit the data from within my `ListView` (update data within the delegate, delete or create new indexes) and then save those changes, make something like an 'little XML editor'.

My question is: how could I save the changed data to the `dataModel` of the `ListView`? I'm thinking I can again cycle trough every index and somehow add, delete certain indexes or update them, saving those changes in an XML file, then load it up to again to reflect those changes in the listview, but that sounds complicated and i hope there is a better and somewhat cleaner way.

Is there a C++ way of manipulaing data models of `ListView`s?

Could I transfer XML data into C++ and use that as a souce for the listView, could that method grant better and easier manipulation of the data model? I'd like to avoid creating and loading XML file for every change.

Quick and small example of the `ListView`:

```js
    XmlListModel {
        id: model
        query: "/item"
        XmlRole {name: "title"; query: "title/string()"}
        XmlRole {name: "lang"; query: "@lang/string()"}
        XmlRole {name: "category"; query: "category/string()"}
    }
```

```js
    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: model
        delegate: modelDelegate
        currentIndex: 0
    }
```

```js
    Component {
        id: modelDelegate
        Rectangle {
            id: container
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: title
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                   //editing of the text, there will be `TextEdit here etc.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As I'm still learning QML and its awesome so far, I'd really appreciate pointers into right direction or some small examples of the proof of concept if there are any, thank you all upfront.

Comment: I think `XmlListModel` is kinda readonly item. Since `XmlListModel.source` or `XmlListModel.xml` point to the same source athough you update a node I guess the only way to change the data is to change the source. But that looks too complicated task for just update a node. The workaround is to create your own XML based model with  functionality you need.

Comment: You're saying I should use something like Qt's `QXmlSimpleReader` to parse the XML in C++, make my own model from it (I'm guessing something like JSON object or is there something even better?) and use that as a `LisView`'s source? Could I then edit that model regardless of the source?

Comment: I guess you should create your own model derived from `QAbstractListModel` (btw as XmlListModel [does](https://github.com/cedrus/qt/blob/master/qtdeclarative/src/imports/xmllistmodel/qqmlxmllistmodel_p.h)) and so add some XML manipulating tool as a data source. And yes, a model could be editable.

Comment: I couldn't find any concrete examples of this conversion and since my knowledge of C++in Qt environment is lower than needed here, could you mock up a simple parser using c++ to do this? (I've setup a header file in my project in which to do the conversion, but struggling to do any more)

Comment: See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpledommodel-example.html) example. It's readonly tree model but it will be enough for beginning. After you understand the concept it could be easy to convert it to editable tree.

Comment: After spending about 45 mins reading this I can say "oh my god this is science fiction". I don't understand 99% of it. There must be something easier that I can use in C++ just to get to the contents of a simple XML file and convert the data to JSON so i can send it do my Javascript functions in QML...